# Разметка Listview и производительность

Tags: android, listview, android-layout

Имеется 10 listview. Для каждого есть свой кастомный адаптер. В адаптерах переопределен метод getView.

Сейчас имеется одна разметка на всех. В этой разметке есть все необходимые виджеты для listview скрытые на разметке. В каждом адаптере использую visiblity GONE или VISIBLE.

Скажите, что будет лучше по производительность одна разметка на все listview или для каждого своя? Просто слышал, что xml разметка тратит много ресурсов, поэтому и сделал один на всех,но что то сомневаюсь что правильно я делаю.

Answer (score 4):

Правильнее делать для каждого адаптера свою разметку.

> ..xml разметка тратит много ресурсов...

Это значит что плохо построенная xml долго отрисовывается. Поэтому для каждого адаптера лучше делать xml с минимальным количеством view, а не пихать все в одну xml. Хотя view у которых visibility=gone не отрисовываются. Но вы будете тогда тратить время в адаптаре для того чтобы выполнить setVisibility(VISIBLE) каждой view которую нужно отобразить. 
В общем делайте разные xml для разных адаптеров

Comment: но так же не забудь про ViewHolder

Comment: тогда уж сразу надо переходить на ресайклер

Answer (score 3):

Действительно работа с xml довольно ресурсозатратная операция. Поэтому лучше использовать разные разметки и желательно с применением паттерна ViewHolder, который способствует увеличению производительности. Если проект только создается, то можно рассмотреть использование RecyclerView в качестве альтернативы ListView. При этом использование паттерна ViewHolder становится уже обязательным.

Comment: ViewHolder  использую во всех адаптерах как private final ViewHolder.RecyclerView  надо же докачивать как я понял,это увеличить размер apk.Я впринципе уже на 60% закончил

Comment: У RecyclerView несколько иная логика работы, но ничего там "докачивать" не надо

Comment: Чем она лучше и стоит ли мне из-за нее переделывать проект?

Comment: задайте отдельный вопрос про сравнение ListView и RecyclerView и я на него развернуто отвечу. комментарии не позволят написать развернутый ответ.

Comment: Вот вам хороший ответ почему стоит использовать RecyclerView вместо ListView http://stackoverflow.com/a/28886129/7104538

Comment: А я на хабре почитал что он труден в риализации

Comment: да, он действительно несколько сложнее в освоении, но оно того стоит. К тому же Андроид его позиционирует как замену Listview и не только ему..

Comment: Еще вопрос.У меня 1 listview заменяем 10.Может то же их надо 10 создать?